# Download button downloads only 145 rows in DataTables with Scroller

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

We're sometimes handling tables with more than 400 000 rows, we are using server-side processing plug-in Scroller for DataTable on our page. We also want to download the table, but with the Scroller plug-in it always downloads only 145 rows. Can I somehow tell the download buttons to download full table and not only the loaded part?

I'm doing this completely in R-Shiny with DT package, so any suggestions from this side would be also very appreciated.

Comment: Probably you are looking for `downloadHandler()`. Take a look on the next [page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html)

Comment: Thank you, this was the only option that came into my mind. But then we lose the fancy usability to copy the table into clipboard = some JavaScript magic would be much more appreciated. :-)

Comment: Look [here](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) on `TableTools` extension (point 9). Anyway I think you can use data.table extensions and downloadHandler separately

Comment: I guess `downloadHandler()` plus `input$tableId_rows_all` should get you there (http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html). Note `tableId_rows_all` is a feature of the current development version of DT: https://github.com/rstudio/DT