# Buttons: download button with scroller downloads only few rows

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am handling tables with more than 100 000 rows and using `DT` package (*development version 0.1.56*) to visualize it in Shiny App.

Furthermore I am using `DT` Extensions as: `Buttons`, to download the data in different formats. However while `Scroller` extension is as well activated, i am able only to download few rows (not all data).

Sample code:

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris,extensions=c("Buttons",'Scroller'),options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                               buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),scrollY = 50,
                                               scroller = TRUE
      ))
  }
)
```

Additionally if i run only this part of the code in R and get the datatable in the viewer, i am able to copy etc. all rows, how it is even possible?

```
library("DT")
datatable(
  iris,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
  )
)
```

I have tried different approaches:

1. Changing `scrollY =` ... in the option list -> it is working but the number of `scrollY` has to be huge to actually display all data rows so it could be downloaded fully --> not good approach, as my data comes from Database, i obtain different number of rows plus it makes the app extremally slow
2. Using pageLength option: `pageLength = ..., lengthMenu=c(..,..,..,..)`

However the option to choose is not displayed at all...

Any ideas how i can solve this problem?

- **I am aware about** `downloadHandler()` approach, however **i would prefer to do it through** `DT` as the available Extensions give nice and elegant way, which allows to download the data in different formats at once such as pdf, excel,csv and print.

**I have seen already the same question:

[Download button downloads only 145 rows in DataTables with Scroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645588/download-button-downloads-only-145-rows-in-datatables-with-scroller)

but it has not been answered in the meaning of `DT` package

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you add `server=FALSE` in `DT::renderDataTable`?

Comment: Hi Carl, actually that is working perfectly! Thanks! If You post it as an answer i am going to accept it straight away

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that when `server=TRUE` only the data being displayed is being sent to the client. Setting `server=FALSE` renders all the DT stuff in the client so all the data is there.

Comment: When I use server = FALSE i have this error : DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Answer (score 11):

It is indeed `server = TRUE` that does the trick.

Here is the code since some people like me might put the argument in the wrong place.

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(server = FALSE,{
      DT::datatable(iris,
                    extensions=c("Buttons",'Scroller'),
                    options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                   buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 
                                               'excel', 'pdf', 
                                               'print'),
                                   scrollY = 50,
                                   scroller = TRUE)
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: When I use server = FALSE i have this error : DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/1